# Java how to stream a list inside a list for an object?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, collections, java-stream

So I have lists stored inside of another list.
And inside of that lists there a different objects.
I want to get a specific object based on an attribute.

```
Human robert = building.getRoomList()
    .stream()
    .filter(room -> room.getEmployeeList()
         .stream()
         .filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert")))
    .findFirst().get();
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I solved it by working around. But it would be cool to do it in one line of code. 

Human robert = null;

  for (Room room : building.getRoomList()) {

   robert = room.getRoomList().stream().filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert")).findFirst().get();
   if (robert != null) {
    break;
   }
  }

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it work?

`Stream::filter` requires a `Predicate<T>` and returns the very same `Stream<T>`. As long as you nest `filter` in `filter`, this would never work because the outer one requires `Predicate<T>` while the inner one returns `Stream<T>` which is clearly not compatible.

You might want to use `flatMap`:

```
Human robert = building.getRoomList()
    .stream()                                     // Stream<Room>
    .flatMap(room -> room                         // Stream<Human> flatmapped from:
        .getEmployeeList()                        // .. for each Room get List<Human>
        .stream()                                 // .. for each Room have Stream<Human>
        .filter(human -> human.getName()          // .. for each Room keep the one named
                              .equals("Robert"))) // .. Robert
    .findFirst()                                  // find the first Robert, the Human 
    .orElse(null);                                // or result in null
```

Remember the predicate `human -> human.getName().equals("Robert"))` is not null-safe neither when `human` is `null` nor when its name is `null`. For the null-safety, flat-map like this:

```
    .flatMap(room -> room.getEmployeeList()
                         .stream()
                         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                         .filter(human -> "Robert".equals(human.getName())))
```

Comment: Thank You very much Nikolas!
There are a view great answer for my question. But yours is perfect.
Simple to understand and exactly what I wanted.

Have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```java
Human robert = building.getRoomList().stream()
    .map(Room::getRoomList)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert"))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Robert not found!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Stream.flatMap`:

```
Optional<Human> robert = building.getRoomList().stream()
    .flatMap(room -> room.getEmployeeList().stream())
    .filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert"))
    .findFirst();

robert.ifPresent(r -> /* do something with Robert */);
```

`Stream.flatMap` maps each `room` to a stream of `human`s and the returned stream consists of all the humans of all the rooms, flattened (i.e. not as sublists or substreams).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `.findFirst()` on `RoomList` only but you need to do `.findFirst()` on inner list means `EmployeeList` of every `Room` also and transform `Room` into `Human` using `.map()`, like

```
building.getRoomList()
.stream()
.map(room -> room.getEmployeeList()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert"))
                 .findFirst().get())
.findFirst().get();
```

Which can be simplified using `flatMap` to flatten then `EmployeeList` then get `findFirst`

```
building.getRoomList()
        .flatMap(e -> room.getEmployeeList().stream())
        .filter(human -> human.getName().equals("Robert"))
        .findFirst().get();
```

Note: It's better to use `.orElse()` rather calling `.get()`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401743/why-did-this-performance-question-warrant-not-only-closure-but-deletion-too